# Command to copy a file every 10 min only when Firefox is open

Tags: batch-file, firefox, command-line

I would like to copy a file every 10 minutes when Firefox is open. 
I am not sure what is the best way to do that but so far I have created a `.bat` that I wanted to link to a task in Task Scheduler that will run it every 10 minutes.

This is the command in the `.bat` :

```
copy "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\zotero.sqlite" "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\Zotero_Backup_sqlite\zotero_%date%.sqlite"
```

But Task Scheduler doesn't allow me to add a condition (= run only if firefox is open) nor to run a task every 10 minutes.

So here are my questions:

1. If a .bat is a good way to do this, how can I run a .bat with those two parameters?
2. If a .bat is not a good way to do this, what method would you recommend?

Comment: _Task Scheduler_ **does** allow to run a task every 10 minutes (look for _Triggers_); so you could let _Task Scheduler_ to do the timing, and put the condition into the task script itself: `2> nul tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" /FI "STATUS eq running" | > nul find /I "firefox.exe" || exit /B` (this skips the rest of the script if `firefox.exe` is not running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "firefox.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" copy "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\zotero.sqlite" "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\Zotero_Backup_sqlite\zotero_%date%.sqlite"
timeout /t 600 /nobreak
goto loop
```

This would be a standalone batch-script you would have to start yourself, or put in the startup folder.

You could also just take the

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "firefox.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" copy "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\zotero.sqlite" "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\Zotero_Backup_sqlite\zotero_%date%.sqlite"
```

and run that every 10 minutes from task scheduler ofcourse.

You could also make this into your firefox shorcut and end it when the program isn't active anymore, like this:

```
@echo off
set programName=firefox.exe
start %programName%
:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %programName%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%programName%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0"  copy "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\zotero.sqlite" "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\Zotero_Backup_sqlite\zotero_%date%.sqlite"
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" exit /b
timeout /t 600 /nobreak
goto loop
```

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot Dennis! Would it be possible to run the .bat only when I launch Firefox (to avoid having this .bat running when I am not working on Firefox-Zotero)?

Comment: You can't wait until you start firefox, but you can use it like a shortcut to start both this batch file and firefox simultaniously, see my updated answer. Also, if you feel this answered your question you should click the check next to my answer to mark it.

Comment: Super, Awesome! Thanks a lot Dennis especially because my question in the comment wasn't actually part of the Question above. Thanks so much!